# Как сделать progress bar для slick slider отображающий прогресс количества страниц?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js, progress-bar

Как сделать `progress bar` для `slick slider` отображающий прогресс количества страниц?
Т.е. не прогресс отображения текущего слайда, а прогресс скролла на масштабе всего слайдера.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var time = 2;
  var $bar,
      $slick,
      isPause,
      tick,
      percentTime;
  
  $slick = $('.slider');
  $slick.slick({
    draggable: true,
    adaptiveHeight: false,
    dots: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    pauseOnDotsHover: true,
  });
  
  $bar = $('.slider-progress .progress');
  $barRound = $('.progress');
  
  $('.slider-wrapper').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      isPause = true;
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      isPause = false;
    }
  })
  
  function startProgressbar() {
    resetProgressbar();
    percentTime = 0;
    isPause = false;
    tick = setInterval(interval, 10);
  }
  var $rbar = $('.progress circle');
var rlen = 2 * Math.PI * $rbar.attr('r');
  function interval() {
    
    percentTime += 1 / (time + 0.1);
    $bar.css({
      width: percentTime + '%'
    });
    $rbar.css({
      'stroke-dasharray': rlen,
      'stroke-dashoffset': rlen * (1 - percentTime / 100)
    });

    if (percentTime >= 100) {
      $slick.slick('slickNext');
      startProgressbar();
    }
 
  }
  
  
  function resetProgressbar() {
    $bar.css({
     width: 0+'%' 
    });
    clearTimeout(tick);
  }
  
  startProgressbar();
  
});

// circle bar
```

```css
.progress circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #00d6d6;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper" id="slick-1">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">your content</div>
    <div class="slide">your content</div>
    <div class="slide">your content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-progress">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-round__wrap">
      <svg class="progress">
        <circle r="50" cx="150" cy="80"/>
      </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setProgress(index) {
  const calc = ((index + 1) / ($slider.slick('getSlick').slideCount)) * 100;

  $progressBar
    .css('background-size', `${calc}% 100%`)
    .attr('aria-valuenow', calc);

  $progressBarLabel.text(`${calc.toFixed(2)}% completed`);
}

const $slider = $('.slider');
const $progressBar = $('.progress');
const $progressBarLabel = $('.slider__label');

$slider.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {   
  setProgress(nextSlide);
});

$slider.slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  speed: 400,
});  

setProgress(0);
```

```css
.progress {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, black);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0 100%;
  
  transition: background-size 0.4s ease-in-out;
}




/**
 *  Demo Styles from the Slick Slider
 *  website
 */

body {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.content {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 600px;
}

.slider {
  margin: 30px auto 50px;
}

.image {
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz1.png" alt="">
      </div> <!-- end image -->
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz4.png" alt="">
      </div> <!-- end image -->
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz3.png" alt="">
      </div> <!-- end image -->
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png" alt="">
      </div> <!-- end image -->
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz5.png" alt="">
      </div> <!-- end image -->
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz6.png" alt="">
      </div> <!-- end image -->
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end slider -->
  <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="slider__label"></div>
</div> <!-- end content -->
```

Решение взято отсюда: https://jsfiddle.net/qd8Lab7f/